# Using custom func in Go condition template

Tags: function, go, templates, go-templates

I'm trying to define a custom Go func to use in a template condition.
What I want to achieve is : if the given argument is an IPv4 address the template will output *IPv4: [argument]* else it will output *IPv6: [argument]*.

To do that I have created a template like this:

```
{{ range .Addresses }}
{{ if IsIPv4 . }}
IPv4: {{ . }}
{{ else }}
IPv6: {{ . }}
{{ end }}
{{ end }}
```

As you can see I have create a new function called **IsIPv4** which take a string argument and given the argument return true or false. Here is the code:

```
var (
    errNotAnIPAddress = errors.New("The argument is not an IP address")
)

func isIPv4(address string) (bool, error) {
    ip := net.ParseIP(address)

    if ip == nil {
        return false, errNotAnIPAddress
    }

    return (ip.To4() != nil), nil
}
```

When executing my template I have got no errors but the execution looks like to stop when trying to evaluate **{{ if IsIPv4 . }}**.

Of course the function is mapped before trying to parse and execute the template.

```
funcMap := template.FuncMap{
    "IsIPv4": isIPv4,
}
```

I'm pretty new to Go and I have probably missed something (maybe obvious?).

To debug a little bit I have tried to remove the IsIPv4 call in my template giving a condition like **{{ if . }}**. And the result was to always output *IPv4: [the IP address]*. That makes sense to me.

I also took a look at the predefined Go funcs like **eq** and it looks like I'm trying to reproduce the same idea, without any success.

Comment: Are you adding the function map `funcMap` to the template? You need to call a template's `Funcs` method to do that. Details: https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#Template.Funcs

Comment: @abhink of course I did that. Otherwise it would tell me that the function is not defined while parsing the template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR;** You must inspect the `error` value returned by [`template.Execute()`](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#Template.Execute) or [`template.ExecuteTemplate()`](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#Template.ExecuteTemplate) which will tell you why it doesn't work for you.

---

#### Things that could go wrong

First, your execution doesn't panic because it simply returns an error. Would you inspect that, you'll probably know what's going wrong immediately:

```
if err := t.Execute(os.Stdout, data); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Next what could go wrong: you have to register your custom functions *prior* to parsing the template because the template engine needs to be able to statically analyze the template, and it needs to know prior that `IsIPv4` is a function name:

```
t := template.Must(template.New("").Funcs(template.FuncMap{
    "IsIPv4": isIPv4,
}).Parse(templ))
```

Another potential error is that `isIPv4()` expects a value of type `string`, and you may pass a value of different type.

And custom functions registered for templates should only return a non-`nil` error if you intend to stop the execution of the template. Because that's what happens if you return an `error`. [`template.FuncMap`](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#FuncMap):

> [...] if the second (error) return value evaluates to non-nil during execution, execution terminates and Execute returns that error.

#### Working example

Here's a working example using your template and your `isIPv4()` function:

```
t := template.Must(template.New("").Funcs(template.FuncMap{
    "IsIPv4": isIPv4,
}).Parse(templ))

m := map[string]interface{}{
    "Addresses": []string{"127.0.0.1", "0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1"},
}

if err := t.Execute(os.Stdout, m); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/6CXSOyAbMO)):

```
IPv4: 127.0.0.1

IPv6: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
```

#### Potential errors

The above program prints the following errors:

Passing an invalid IP:

```
    "Addresses": []string{"127.0.0.1.9"},
```

Output:

```
panic: template: :2:6: executing "" at <IsIPv4 .>: error calling IsIPv4:
    The argument is not an IP address
```

Passing a non-`string` value:

```
    "Addresses": []interface{}{2},
```

Output:

```
panic: template: :2:13: executing "" at <.>: wrong type for value; expected string; got int
```

Attempting to register your custom function *after* the template has been parsed:

```
t := template.Must(template.New("").Parse(templ))
t.Funcs(template.FuncMap{
    "IsIPv4": isIPv4,
})
```

Output:

```
panic: template: :2: function "IsIPv4" not defined
```

Comment: OK I see.
Thanks for the really detailed answer, which actually answered my question.
I had indeed an error while executing the template.
`at <.>: wrong type for value; expected string; got net.IP`
Meaning I already have a net.IP struct instead of a string, so my function doesn't work.
Thanks again!