# How to test if a value is a string in a template

Tags: string, go, types, go-templates

I would like to find out if it is possible and if so how, to test if a value is a string in a Go template.

I have tried the following with no success

```
{{- range .Table.PrimaryKeys.DBNames.Sorted }}{{ with (index $colsByName .)}}
{{ .Name }}: {{ if .IsArray }}[]{{ end }}'{{.Type}}', {{end}}
{{- end }}
{{- range $nonPKDBNames }}{{ with (index $colsByName .) }}
    {{ .Name }}: {{ if .IsArray }}[]{{end -}} {
  type: {{ if .Type IsString}}GraphQLString{{end -}}, # line of interest where Type is a value that could be a number, string or an array
}, {{end}}
{{- end }}
```

And this is the error that I get

> Error: error parsing TablePaths: error parsing contents template: template: templates/table.gotmpl:42: function "IsString" not defined

Comment: What is `.Type` you want to test? Please show a [mcve].

Comment: That is not important because `Type` in this sample is simply a value.

Comment: It's important because judging by its name, it looks you store the type as something like `reflect.Type`, which would change how to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 5):

### With a custom function

There is no predeclared `IsString()` function available in templates, but we may easily register and use such a function:

```
t := template.Must(template.New("").Funcs(template.FuncMap{
    "IsString": func(i interface{}) bool {
        _, ok := i.(string)
        return ok
    },
}).Parse(`{{.}} {{if IsString .}}is a string{{else}}is not a string{{end}}`))
fmt.Println(t.Execute(os.Stdout, "hi"))
fmt.Println(t.Execute(os.Stdout, 23))
```

This will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/j9KvOREyx5U)):

```
hi is a string<nil>
23 is not a string<nil>
```

(The `<nil>` literals at the end of lines are the error values returned by the template execution, telling there were no errors.)

### Using `printf` and `%T` verb

We may also do this without custom functions. There is a [`printf`](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#hdr-Functions) function available by default, which is an alias for [`fmt.Sprintf()`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Sprintf). And there is a `%T` verb which outputs the argument's type.

The idea is to call `printf %T` on the value, and compare the result with `"string"`, and we're done:

```
t := template.Must(template.New("").
    Parse(`{{.}} {{if eq "string" (printf "%T" .)}}is a string{{else}}is not a string{{end}}`))
fmt.Println(t.Execute(os.Stdout, "hi"))
fmt.Println(t.Execute(os.Stdout, 23))
```

This will also output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/8U1yZDfMR6h)):

```
hi is a string<nil>
23 is not a string<nil>
```

Comment: Where do I register this function? I am writing a go template that I pass to this package https://gnorm.org. So it is not very clear to me where I would add this code so that I may be able to use it in the template that I have referenced above.

Comment: @brandNew Custom functions must be registered prior to parsing the template text, because the template engine needs to be able to statically analyze the template, and it needs to know prior which literals designate valid custom functions. If you don't have access to the template to do this, use the 2nd approach (with the `printf` function) which doesn't require registering custom functions. For details, see [Using custom func in Go condition template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38586651/using-custom-func-in-go-condition-template/38587070#38587070).